# Undocumented API sonar rule is not working in sonarqube 6.5?

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint

The rule "Public types, methods, and fields (API) should be documented with Javadoc" does not appear to be working in SonarQube 6.5.

I activated the rule in a Java Quality Profile, set the profile as the default, and ran my Java codebase through `mvn sonar:sonar` command.

It did not pick up any violations of this rule, even though some methods are missing Javadoc.
Other rules work fine at picking up violations.

My Test class is something like this:

```
package counter;

/**
 * This is a Javadoc comment
 */
public class MyClass {    

 public static final int DEFAULT_STATUS = 0;    // Compliant - static constant
 private int status;                           // Compliant - not public

 public String message;                  // Noncompliant

 public MyClass() {                         // Noncompliant - missing documentation
   this.status = DEFAULT_STATUS;
 }

 public void setStatus(int status) {  // Compliant - setter
   this.status = status;
 }

 protected int doSomething() {
     return status + 24;// Compliant - not public
 }

 public int doSomething2(int value) {  // Noncompliant
     int a = value*8;
     return a*1;
 }

 public int doSomething3(int value) {  // Noncompliant
   return value*9;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Got it.
At Default Settings, `UndocumentedAPI` rule is working for api packages (packages which contain `api` in their names) only.

During rule activation, a prompt menu asks for a pattern of classes which should run this rule. As depicted in the image:

[image]

Now we can easily change this setting as we want.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this was an [issue](https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx/issues/1248) in SonarQube 6.5. What you can do is upgrade to SonarQube 6.7.7, update all the plugins, check the activation of the rule in the profile used and try it again. Be aware that the latest LTS version is 7.9 so you should prepare for an upgrade from 6.7.x to 7.9, the next major version. Also update the plugins again.